# В чём разница в смысле между «дар, чтобы стать» и «дар стать»?

Tags: синтаксис, значение-слов, семантика

> У неё есть **дар, чтобы стать** певицей.
>
> У неё есть **дар стать** певицей.

Интересно, чем отличается по смыслу «дар, чтобы стать» от «дар стать»? Возможно, «дар, чтобы стать» используют, когда считают вероятность успеха малой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Интересно, чем отличается по смыслу «дар, чтобы стать» от «дар стать»?

По сути ничем не отличается. Союзы "чтобы" и даже "для того, чтобы" часто можно просто опустить. Сравните: "She has a talent (in order) to become a singer". В русском, правда, "чтобы" не является избыточным, иногда его просто нельзя опустить по соображениям грамматики, но смысла не добавляет.

> Возможно, «дар, чтобы стать» используют, когда считают вероятность
>   успеха малой?

Нет. Ничего подобного я тут не вижу, откуда взялось иное мнение, мне совсем не понятно.
(+)
Я рассматривал проблему только с позиций грамматики и понимания смысла, мнение  том, что фраза не совсем по-русски звучит, отчасти верное: слово "дар" не очень сочетается со "стать". Безупречными в стилистическом отношении были бы, например, такие фразы:

*У неё есть возможность стать певицей.

У неё есть возможность, чтобы стать певицей.

У неё есть возможность для того, чтобы стать певицей.*

Так вот, все три фразы означают одно и тоже. Грамматика, правда, у них разная, что и находит выражение в отсутствии запятой в первом случае.

Answer (score 4):

Грамматически оба варианта возможны, но в обоих просматриваются *смысловые* проблемы. Они связаны с тем, что вместо смысла "**у неё есть дар певицы**" (поэтому ей стоит начать соответствующую карьеру) выражен смысл "**дар** (для) **становления кем-то**" (во втором варианте это звучит прямолинейно и воспринимается совсем неестественно). Поэтому нужна форма выражения, в которой "**становление**" и "**дар**" грамматически *развязаны*, тогда "дар" - даже без отдельных грамматических связей - будет восприниматься как певческий. Например:

> У неё есть дар - как основание стать певицей.
>
> У неё есть дар, и она может стать *хорошей* певицей.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **У неё есть дар, чтобы стать певицей.**

Дар ― это способность к чему-либо, талант, одаренность (в данном случае хорошие вокальные данные). Это **потенциальная возможность,** которую человек сумеет или не сумеет реализовать в будущем (отсюда союз ЧТОБЫ).

**Дар стать ―** неверное сочетание, хотя сочетание с глаголом возможно, например: **дар имитировать.**

Из словаря:

**ДАР** 3. только ед. **Высокая степень одарённости; талант, дарование** (ниспосланная Богом или данная природой). Поэтический, артистический дар. Дар к художественному творчеству. Абсолютный слух - это природный дар. **Такой голос - поистине дар Божий.** // Умение, способность к чему-л. Дар оратора, организатора. Дар имитировать всё и всех. Дар слова (способность членораздельно выражать свои мысли, обычно красиво, выразительно). Потерять дар речи; лишиться дара речи (перестать говорить, замолчать от испуга, смущения и т.п.). Обрести дар речи (заговорить после такого молчания).

Сравнить: У нее есть **возможность** стать певицей (поступить в институт и получить вокальное образование).

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, но позволю себе дополнить: в первом случае ("дар, чтобы...") выражение звучит, на мой слух, не вполне точно и я бы не стал употребять его ни в одном из случаев, заменив слово "дар" на слова "способности / данные", хотя личный вкус -  это ещё не показатель правильности речи.

В первом приближении, получаем, что "дар, чтобы" = "неопределённая вероятность" (есть потенциал, да что-то мешает или может помешать).

"дар стать" = "определённая вероятность, колебания исключены".

То есть различия - в степени решительности, определённости или неопределённости вероятностей.

Интересно, что оборот "у него есть всё..." сочетается только с "чтобы", ср.

***У него есть всё, чтобы стать богатым и знаменитым.***

[астериск] ***У него есть всё стать богатым и знаменитым***.

Во втором случае обязательно требуется дополнение, конкретизация того, что же это такое пресловутое "всё", даже если это "неопределённая определённость" (в данном случае неопределённость выражается множественным числом):

***У него есть все шансы стать богатым и знаменитым.***

***У него есть все права стать процветающим и прославленным дельцом.***

***У него есть все причины стать деловым и успешным.***

Answer (score 1):

Корявая и та и другая фраза. Так по-русски не говорят! Певческий дар - скромненько и со вкусом.

Answer (score 1):

Союз *чтобы* относится к числу **асемантических союзов**, которые выполняют **чисто синтаксическую** роль, указывая на зависимость придаточной части от главной. Таким образом, в ваших примерах ***чтобы* ни на что не влияет**.

Другое дело, что «У неё есть дар, чтобы стать певицей» и «У неё есть дар стать певицей» — речения, звучащие слишком неестественно для русской речи. Но к сути дела это не относится.